# Eliminando la ultima fila de un DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo un DGV en el cual ingreso datos directamente pero cuando creo una nueva fila pero preciono la tecla escape es pq no quiero ingresar datos pero queda una fila en blanco creada entonces esa fila la quiero eliminar, este es mi código. Creando fila.

```
private void btnNuevoClasificacion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvClasificacion.CurrentRow == null)
        {
            dgvClasificacion.Rows.Add();
            dgvClasificacion.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Selected = true;
            dgvClasificacion.BeginEdit(true);
        }
        else
        {
            dgvClasificacion.Rows[dgvClasificacion.Rows.Count - 1].Selected = true;
            dgvClasificacion.Rows.Add();
            DataGridViewRowPosition(dgvClasificacion);
        }  
    }

private void dgvClasificacion_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dgvClasificacion.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = string.Empty;
        ClasificacionTalla item = new ClasificacionTalla();

        DataGridViewRow row = dgvClasificacion.CurrentRow;
        item.Descripcion = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Descripcion))
        {
            _repositoryClasificacionTalla.Create(item);
        }
        //else
        //    dgvClasificacion.Rows.Remove();

    }
```

La idea es que si esta vacía esa fila eliminarla al remove tengo que pasarle el index de la ultima fila para eliminarla. ¿Alguna sugerencia?
[image: Eliminar fila de DGV]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esa fila la muestra el `DataGridView` por defecto para permitir al usuario ingresar nuevos registros, sino quieres visualizarla asigna la propiedad

[DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows(v=vs.110).aspx)

en `false`

**>>cuando agrego una nueva fila pero ya no decido poner algun registro queda una fila en blanco entonces tengo que eliminar esa fila por código**

podrias usar

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1]);
```

Comment: Leandro no, si tengo esa propiedad en mi DGV lo que pasa es que cuando agrego una nueva fila pero ya no decido poner algun registro queda una fila en blanco entonces tengo que eliminar esa fila por código voy actualizar el enunciado.

Comment: Gracias Leandro